# Filter query result in controller or repository class?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, repository

Our controllers in our symfony application often have to filter query results before handing the results over to the view template. What is the best way to filter those query results. At the moment we often have something like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form = $this->getFilterForm();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(...);
    $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('q');

    if ($name = $form->get('name')->getData()) {
        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere('q.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $name);
    }

    if ($birthday = $form->get('birthday')->getData()) {
        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere('q.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $birthday);
    }

    return array(
        'result' => $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult()
    );
}
```

In my opinion this should not be part of the controller. On the other hand I think that putting all of this in a repository class for that entity type could lead to many `filter*` methods for multiple concerns.

Does anyone have a best practice for that or any other clever idea where to put filter methods or how to handle filtering data?

Comment: These filters, and all queries really, should definitely go into the repository. Have you considered traits? They may be able to help you separate out your concerns. Another possibility is an event system, where each subscriber could determine if a specified filter is to be added.

Comment: Although slightly over-engineered IMO, this might be a solution: [On Taming Repository Classes in Doctrine](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/03/04/doctrine_repositories.html). It suggests using Criteria classes to move the filtering logic from your controller and to prevent multiple `filter*` methods.

Comment: @dchesterton I'm glad you mentioned that article.  If you hadn't i would have :)